# javascript method is not returning boolean or ticket calculation method is wrong

Tags: javascript, html

I have to develop a module of booking movie ticket website. This module should contain the below pages:

1. Book Ticket page – This will contain details that will be entered by the user to book train tickets
2. Thank you page – Thank you page appears after user successfully booking a ticket

Ticket Fare should be calculated based on the below logic. (Use Java script for doing the calculation).

o   Ticket Fare =  Fare for 1 ticket * # of tickets

o   Assume fare for 1 ticket is 200.

·         For children the fare of 1 ticket is 100.

·         Once the user submit the form, ticket fare should be calculated and displayed in the alert box as “Your approximate ticket amount is  INR“.

The JavaScript method for calculating ticket price should return a Boolean value.

Example: No of tickets: 4 No of children's:1 then the ticket fare will be 700.

**Application.js:**

```
function myEvaluate()
{
if(document.myForm.tickets.value < document.myForm.childrens.value)
{

   window.alert("No of tickets should be greater than the no of children");
   document.myForm.children.focus();
   return false;
}

var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
var ipStr = document.myForm.showdate.value;
var ip = new Date(ipStr).toISOString().split('T')[0];
if(ip<today)
{
  window.alert("Show date and time should be either current date or future 
                date");
  document.myForm.showdate.focus();
  return false;
}

var totalTix = document.myForm.tickets.value;
var childTix = document.myForm.childrens.value;
var adultTix = totalTix - childTix;
var totalFare = (adultTix*200) + (childTix*100);
alert("Your approximate ticket amount is "+totalFare+ "INR");

return (true);
}
```

**Error I get:**

> com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
>   testWeb(htmlpackage.WebTestAssign2): Have provided all the inputs
>   correctly,  but the ticket calculation is wrong or The javaScript
>   method is not  returning any boolean value

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is the editor in which you code.

Try this

```
function validate()        
{
    var z=document.forms["myForms"]["showdate"].value;
    var x=document.forms["myForms"]["tickets"].value;
    var y=document.forms["myForms"]["childrens"].value;
    if(y>x)
    {
        alert("No of tickets should be greater than the no of children");
    }
    var date=z.substring(0,2);
    var month=z.substring(3,5);
    var year=z.substring(6,10);
    var myDate=new Date(year,month-1,date);
    var today= new Date();
    if(myDate>today)
    {
        alert("Show date and time should be either current date or future date");
    }
    return false;
} 

function ticketprice()
{
    var x=document.forms["myForms"]["tickets"].value;
    var y=document.forms["myForms"]["childrens"].value;
    var ticketfare=(x*200)-(y*100);
    alert("Your approximate ticket amount is "+ticketfare+" INR");
    return true;
}
```